# ValueError: path is on drive c:, start on drive D:

Tags: python, gcloud

I downloaded the google cloud sdk and I'm following the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world) on how to get a nodejs app running on the cloud on app engine. I downloaded the zip file onto my d: drive by the cloud sdk is on the c: drive. When I run the command to deploy the app to the cloud

```
$ gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --set-default
```

I get the error on the command prompt

```
ValueError: path is on drive c:, start on drive D:
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Most likely this is due to an Environment Variable not having the proper path set. Check to make sure they are set correctly. Otherwise you should include the full stacktrace and the output of 'gcloud version
'

Comment: @Ryan What exactly do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=258) in the Cloud SDK.

For now, please work around by installing the Cloud SDK to the same drive as your app, or developing your app on the same drive as the Cloud SDK.